# Archivos borrados luego de un commit

Tags: git

Cree un proyecto de Angular, inicié git y cree una rama develop para comenzar a trabajar. Luego de todo un día de trabajo, hice el build y decidí 'commitear' y hacer el push a GitHub pero cuando terminé me di cuenta que no se estaban guardando los archivos nuevos (posteriores al first commit que hice al crear el proyecto).

Buscando la forma de dar con el repositorio donde estaban 'almacenados' esos archivos cambié de branch y todos los archivos desaparecieron. Solo quedaron modificaciones en el package.json como la dependencia de bootstrap, la carpeta de assets con un logo y los archivos de firebase que instalé al final.

No se que puedo hacer para recuperarlos. Los cambios no fueron commiteados y tanto la rama main como develop fueron sobreescritas con las del first commit conservando algunas modificaciones que mencioné.
Pareciera como si todos los cambios que hice no estuvieran conectados con git pero la carpeta si.

Probé distintas formas de los comandos git checkout y git reset pero nada.

Realmente fue mucho trabajo perdido y lo necesito.

Comment: hiciste un add antes del commit? como hiciste el commit? si estaban en un branch, deben seguir en ese mismo branch...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @gbianchi hice git add . , git commit -m 'commit' y el push con set upstream para crear la rama. Hice el merge con main desde github y ahí vi que no había ningun cambio en el repositorio

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega los pasos que hiciste en la pregunta, los comentarios son volatiles y se pierden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, te recomendaría que mires **con atención** lo que hay en el reflog (ejecuta `git reflog`). Si dices que acometiste, allí debe estar la revisión si no has hecho nada extravagante, independientemente de que haya una rama o no.

Asumiendo que *no hiciste* **commit**, se puede recuperar lo que hiciste **siempre y cuando hayas agregado** (o sea, hayas corrido `git add`).

En el momento en el que se hace `git add`, git introduce todos los objetos necesarios en su base de datos para poder incorporarlos al index. Así que siempre podrías recuperar dichos objetos. Tendrías que mirar **cuales** son dichos objetos... la lista se puede obtener corriendo

```
git fsck --dangling
```

Eso te debería dar una lista de objetos (trees, blobs) que git tiene en la DB y que no están asociados a una rama, stash o revisiones relevantes (como los apuntadores del reflog).. esto no solo incluye los archivos que estás buscando. También se incluirían otros muchos objetos que no son los que buscan por lo que esto podría ser una tarea *no trivial*. Si es un repositorio pequeño, no debería ser demasiado trabajo.... pero si es un proyecto grande.... podría ser una tarea bastaaaaaaaante larga.

Usando `git cat-file -p un-id` podrías ver el contenido de **cada** objeto. Así que el reto sería conseguir los blobs y los trees que conforman el **directorio raíz**.... el problema es que de ninguno de los objetos que vas a ver podrás saber como se llamaba en el directorio raiz, solo podrías ver *su contenido* (si es un blob, el contenido del archivo; si es un *tree*, el listado de archivos *dentro* del directorio).

Si es un blob, podrías hacer una redirección para que quede con el nombre en el directorio raiz:

```
git cat-file -p un-id > unarchivo.txt
```

Y así tienes `unarchivo.txt`. Si es un tree (o sea, un directorio), entonces tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
git read-tree --prefix=el-directorio un-id-de-objeto
```

Con eso repusiste el directorio `el-directorio` (con su contenido) en el index (no te saldría en el árbol de trabajo.... probablemente haya formas de llevarlo al árbol de trabajo pero con tenerlo en el tree ya es bastante ya que te serviría para hacer un commit para que no lo vuelvas a perder).

Tendrías que preocuparte por buscar solo los objetos en la raiz del proyecto. Si son archivos dentro de directorios del proyecto, pues van a quedar en el directorio cuando lo consigas, no hay necesidad de preocuparse por ellos... quiero decir, supon que ejecutas:

```
git cat-file -p un-id | less # mirando el contenido de un blob para saber que tiene
```

Si te das cuenta de que el contenido corresponde a un archivo con una ruta como esta:

```
un-directorio/un-subdirectorio/un-archivo.txt
```

Entonces no te preocupes por el objeto porque *eventualmente* lo vas a recuperar cuando consigas el tree del directorio `un-directorio`.

Eso creo que es suficiente trabajo.

Otro truco que podrías intentar es sacar la lista de todos los IDs que están **incluidos en los trees** que están dangling. Llamemos a esta lista `incluido.txt`:

```
git fsck --dangling 2> /dev/null | grep tree | while read a b elTree; do git cat-file -p $elTree | while read perms type id name; do echo $id; done; done > incluido.txt
```

Ahora tomamos todos los IDs de todos los objetos que están dangling.... los que aparezcan en `incluido.txt` **sabemos** que no los necesitamos porque están incluidos como parte de un directorio... así que hacemos esto:

```
git fsck --dangling 2> /dev/null | while read a b id; do grep $id incluido.txt > /dev/null || echo ID que no esta incluido: $id; done | md5sum
```

*Esa* sería la lista de objetos que tendrías que analizar para saber como se llaman en el directorio raíz y con eso deberías recuperarlo todo.... o casi.

Comment: Increible, tu respuesta eftshift0! Muchas gracias.
En la parte de 'un-id' que id debería ingresar?

En el reflog se puede ver el commit 'deploy' el cual fue el ultimo que hice y donde noté que las modificaciones no se estaban commiteando realmente, me pregunto si al igual que el comando commit, el comando add . tampoco tomo las modif.

Comment: Aquí el reflog
https://imgur.com/a/ltNQHZV

Comment: Añado lo que respondí en otro comentario.
Hice git add . , git commit -m 'commit' y el push con set upstream para crear la rama. Hice el merge con main desde github y ahí vi que no había ningun cambio en el repositorio

Comment: Si tienes el id de la revisión en el reflog, nada está perdido... si te ubicas mejor usando ramas, crea una rama en dicha revisión: `git branch una-rama el-id-de-la-revision-del-log; git checkout una-rama`

Comment: Lo logré! No puedo creerlo. Muchisimas gracias, salvaste mi vida.

Comment: Por cierto, con git branch una-rama el-id-de-la-revision-del-log; git checkout una-rama fue todo muy facil para mi

Comment: La megareceta que puse sirve para el caso en el que no hayas hecho commit. Si habías hecho commit, era una _panza_, como lo acabas de comprobar.

Comment: @eftshift0 quedaría bien el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/549487/archivos-borrados-luego-de-un-commit#comment971998_549500) como segundo párrafo así no se pierde

Comment: Si me preguntan, ese tema no tiene que ver con la pregunta "como recupero lo que acometí que ya no lo veo luego de hacer un checkout?". Gracias por la propuesta, @aloMalbarez

Comment: Aparte... 2do párrafo? Pero si ya siento que escrbí el equivalente en git a **"El Quijote"** :-D